# Vector Drawable Not Overwritten by Build Variant Flavor Dimension

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-vectordrawable, build-variant

I have an app with a base brand and multiple whitelabel brands along with multiple server targets. In my app's build.gradle,the flavors are defined as:
`flavorDimensions("server", "whitelabel")`

In my `src/main/res/drawable` I have a logo.xml VectorDrawable for the base brand and it is overwritten in `src/whitelabel1/res/drawable`.

When my app's build.config contains `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` the correct logo.xml is used in my ImageView. If I remove `useSupportLibrary` the ImageView renders logo.xml from `main` even in the apk for Whitelabel1

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageLogo"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/viewXS"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/marginXS"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:padding="@dimen/marginXS"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_logo" />
```

Answer (score 2):

It happened with me as well. only after writing this
vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
inside defaultconfig. vector resources was picked from the flavor source set folder.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to improve code formatting and include an explaination of how this works and why it is solution of the problem described in the question. See [answer].

Comment: Is this also the case for non-vector drawables like PNGs?

Comment: @Daniel: No, for PNGs it's working out of the box.